# resize and cache images with php and use mod_rewrite to acces the cashed ones

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, image-processing, kohana

I want to resize images with the size in the url like this:
http://www.domain.nl/images/chached/200x200/name.jpg
If the image doesn't exist I want to generate and cache it.

How do I after that check if the file exists, with out having to generate the folder '200x200' in the /images/chached/ directory and without the use of PHP(slower).

Is there a way to do this with mod_rewrite(faster)? Or is this just not possible?

I'm using Kohana 3 witch uses this mod_rewite code:

```
# Turn on URL rewriting
RewriteEngine On
# Installation directory
# RewriteBase /kohana/
RewriteBase /

# Protect hidden files from being viewed
<Files .*>
    Order Deny,Allow
Deny From All
</Files>

# Protect application and system files from being viewed
RewriteRule ^(?:application|modules|system)\b.* index.php/$0 [L]

# Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Kohana's routing to set up a new route `/images/cached/<size>/<name>` (or similar) and let it be handled by an action of your choice. Then, in the code for that action, generate the image from those parameters, save the result under that path, AND serve the image to the client.

So the first request (file doesn't exist) goes straight to index.php (because `RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT]`), the second and every following request will be served by Apache directly (because now `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` doesn't match anymore).

Comment: thanks for anwsering: I was wandering if it was possible not to create the path: '/images/cached/the_size/the_name.jpg' but to process this link with mod_rewrite. e.g. When the file '/images/cached/200x200/the_name.jpg' is generated, cached and saved in the '/images/cached/' directory. I want mod_rewrite to map '/images/cached/200x200/the_name.jpg' to '/images/cached/the_name.jpg'. So I don't have to create a lot of folders in the cache directory.

Comment: How would you handle multiple sizes then? If that's not a requirement, just lose the size (or include in filename), so you don't have to create folders (images/cached/name_200x200.jpg).

Comment: Thanks again. Well, I want multiple sizes, so I think I'll stick to the folder option. It just doesn't feel like the best option. But speed has a high priority, and making a php request for every image is not gonna speed things up.

Comment: You're only making a php request for every *first* call on a given parameter combination, after that it's just Apache serving static files. Do you need to create all images in advance and have them stored in the cache dir? I really don't see a reason for having a RewriteRule afterwards like you suggested...

Comment: You're right. I want to create the images on the fly. What would a Kohana Route look like? The folowing doesn't seem te work. `Route::set('imgs', 'static/imgs/cached/<size>/<name>')
 ->defaults(array(
 'directory'  => '',
 'controller' => 'work',
 'action'     => 'index',
  ));`

Comment: The above doesn't seem to work beacuse of the dot in the filename static/imgs/cached/50/1.jpg without the dot the routes works!? but then it isn't a filename anymore. strange.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know a thing about Kohana. I'm a Symfony guy myself. ;) But in principle, it looks good: You define controller and action as default, and handle parameters in the URL. How does it fail? What happens if you call `static/imgs/cached/200x200/test.jpg`?

Comment: Oh, okay, Kohana probably treats the dot as a separator. In Symfony, there is a configuration variable that governs which characters should be considered a separator, maybe Kohana has a similar setting? Or you could use `.../<name>.<ext>` and put it back together manually. (Avoiding any other dots in <name> and <ext>)

Comment: I dont no if Kohana has such a conf var but `.../<name>.<ext>` works fine. You really helped me a lot. Thanks very much!